# Creating 2 directories in a different location

Tags: linux, mkdir

sample_dir2

-- sample_dir

```
|-- admin
|-- cambridge

|   `-- security
|       |-- annex
|       `-- parking
|-- history.exe
|-- markham
|   |-- annex
|   |-- building1
|   `-- parking
`-- stenton
    |-- gen_ed
    |   `-- Holidays
    `-- lib_arts
        `-- english.txt
```

Your current directory is stenton. Create a new directory called payroll within a new directory called accounting, which should be in admin:
I've tried quite a few ways like:

```
mkdir home/sample_dir2/sample_dir/admin/accounting/payroll

mkdir ../admin/accounting/payroll
```

Comment: Does your coursework show you the -p option for mkdir? Or suggest a man page to read?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211656/copying-and-relative-home#comment358558_211656 and http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4206/117549

Answer (score 3):

Although the due date for this assignment may be passed for you (and since your account is unregistered you may not even see this), but for any future ULI101 students who run into the same problem:

The missing part of your second attempt was likely the `-p` flag to mkdir:

```
mkdir -p ../admin/accounting/payroll
```

Another way to solve the problem would be to create the intermediate directory first, then the final directory:

```
mkdir ../admin/accounting
mkdir ../admin/accounting/payroll
```

Refer to your coursework, or it may eventually point you to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) for `mkdir`, which says:

> -p, --parents
>
> no error if existing, make parent directories as needed